# Does Java VisualVM gives correct Heap Size of heap dump (.hprof file)

Tags: java, visualvm, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am analyzing a OutOfMemory issue. I got a dump of 800 MB (.hprof file) when i open it in MAT it shows heap size 53.2 MB as below

[image]

Same dump i opened in Java VisualVM and I see Heap size around 769 MB

> ```
>   Date taken: Tue Mar 18 05:25:59 IST 2014
>     File: C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Memory\MemoryDump.hprof
>     File size: 789.1 MB
>     Total bytes: 768,683,549
>     Total classes: 9,288
>     Total instances: 7,081,010
>     Classloaders: 2,924
>     GC roots: 2,496
>     Number of objects pending for finalization: 0
> ```

I read one [article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#MAT_Does_Not_Show_the_Complete_Heap) which shows MAT skips unreachable objects so doesnt report exact heap size.

What does Total Bytes of VisulaVM shows here  : Heap Size or (Heap + Non Heap size) or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

`Total Bytes` is the sum of the size of all the objects in the heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse MAT removes the unreachable object and other junk left over by GC in JVM. Read more:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#Problems_Interpreting_Results